# Rails architecture for authentication without persisting data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, authentication, websocket

Here is the problem. Im trying to build a rails app in which the user logs in, creates other models, and chat with other users. The issue here is that Im not persisting any of the data created by the user in my db, but rather sending it to a nodejs api. How would I go about building something like this.

Thank you very much in advanced

Comment: Token based authentication.

Comment: you could use o-auth and have them log in via facebook, google, etc and save information about the user in cookies or session data

Comment: @TallPaul Hi Paul the api endpoint is an app built with nodejs, thats were all the information from the user is stored.

Comment: @max Do you know any tutorials on the web, all I have found is rails as the api